# Identifying sites enabled for FPX in IIS6

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, web-server

We are running a server running a couple of hundred sites on a Server 2003/II6 setup. We're looking to migrate as many of these users as possible to a Server 2008R2/IIS7.5 setup. Which of course doesn't support our old faithful friend, Frontpage Extensions ([IIS.net article on FPX End-of-Life](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/134/installing-the-frontpage-server-extensions-on-iis-70/)).

We've been looking for a way to highlight those sites which are currently enabled for FPX but haven't found anything particularly obvious so far ... does anyone know how we might be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From very-hazy memory, the frontpage extension state of the sites is stored in a single file somewhere, like in the _vti* folders at the root of the site. Otherwise, I think you can do it from the file system if there's not a metabase property you can ADSUTIL your way to, again, using those _vti folders.